# Python Queue.get(block=False) with non-empty Queue. Can it raise Queue.empty?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm using python's Queue.Queue to synchronize several threads. First, a Queue is populated with N elements, as in

```
N = 10
q = Queue.Queue()
for i in range(N):
  q.put(i)
```

Then, several threads consume the elements from the queue with block=False

```
q.get(block=False)
```

My question is: can the previous call to Queue.get() raise Queue.Empty in any of the first N calls?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to read [the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/Queue.py) to find this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `N` calls to `get()` will succeed; `q.get(block=False)` will only raise `Queue.Empty` if the queue is actually empty. All the calls to `get` made by your threads are synchronized, so the first N threads that get the mutex used by the `Queue` will successfully `get` an item from the `Queue`. If you have N+1 or more threads, any `get` beyond the Nth will raise `Queue.Empty`. This is fairly easy to see for yourself by looking at the relevant parts of the `Queue` code, as mentioned by [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102441/eric).

```
class Queue:
    """Create a queue object with a given maximum size.

    If maxsize is <= 0, the queue size is infinite.
    """
    def __init__(self, maxsize=0):
        self.maxsize = maxsize
        self._init(maxsize)
        self.mutex = _threading.Lock()
        self.not_empty = _threading.Condition(self.mutex)
        ... # Stuff we don't care about

    def get(self, block=True, timeout=None):
        self.not_empty.acquire() # Only on thread can hold this at a time
        try:
            if not block:
                if not self._qsize(): # If there's nothing in the Queue
                    raise Empty
            ... # Other stuff we don't care about, since you use block=False
            item = self._get()
            self.not_full.notify()
            return item
        finally:
            self.not_empty.release()

    def _init(self, maxsize):
        self.queue = deque()

    def _qsize(self, len=len):
        return len(self.queue)
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I'm tagging your answer as the valid one because you showed the relevant code in it, but thanks @Eric.